# Virtual interface and different IPs

Tags: ip, network-interface

I've created a virtual interface on wlan0 with the `ifconfig` comand and here is what I have:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW c4:46:19:69:b7:a5  
          indirizzo inet:192.168.1.4  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Maschera:255.255.255.0
          indirizzo inet6: fe80::c646:19ff:fe69:b7a5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:277003 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:121609 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          Byte RX:329915637 (329.9 MB)  Byte TX:17663121 (17.6 MB)

wlan0:1   Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW c4:46:19:69:b7:a5  
          indirizzo inet:172.16.1.4  Bcast:172.16.255.255  Maschera:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

I made the same thing one a second pc on my local network and doing `ping 172.16.1.7` everything works.

But I don't understand one thing, because I have two IPs which one is chosen to send the icmp request? the original one `192.168.1.4` or the one I created `172.16.1.4`?

Answer (score 1):

It's determined by the routing policy rules in the kernel. You can check what the kernel will use if you run:

```
$ ip route get 172.16.1.7
172.16.1.7 dev wlan0 src 172.16.1.4
```

You can display the routing table (which also shows the source address it will use for traffic over that route) with `ip route show` or `ip ro` for short.

When using `ping` with `-I`, you can specify which interface to use:

```
ping -I 172.16.1.4 172.16.1.7
```

Comment: @dirkt It looks like `-I IFACE/IP should work not only for ping from [iputils](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/) but also for ping from [busybox](https://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#ping), right?

Answer (score 0):

The "virtual interfaces" (`wlan0:1` etc.) are just the old way to tell the kernel that more than one IPv4 address is associated with a network interface. In a modern kernel, these interfaces don't really exist, and they are not shown when you use `ip addr`. Instead, just all assigned IPv4 addresses are listed (here shown for one end of a veth-pair):

```
$ sudo ifconfig veth0b:1 add 10.0.0.2
$ sudo ifconfig
veth0b: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
    inet6 fe80::801e:15ff:fe73:e98a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 82:1e:15:73:e9:8a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 58  bytes 7700 (7.5 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 15  bytes 1174 (1.1 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth0b:1:0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.0.2  netmask 0.0.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
    ether 82:1e:15:73:e9:8a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

$ ip addr show dev veth0b
2: veth0b@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
     link/ether 82:1e:15:73:e9:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
  inet 10.0.0.1/24 scope global veth0b
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet 10.0.0.2/0 scope global veth0b:1:0
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 fe80::801e:15ff:fe73:e98a/64 scope link 
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

In particular, you can't choose a "virtual interfaces" as an interface to bind to:

```
$ ping -I veth0b:1 10.0.0.254
ping: invalid source address veth0b:1
```

But you can choose the source IP address for the ping (which amounts to the same thing):

```
$ ping -I 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.254
$ ping -I 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.254
```

This has really nothing to do with routing or gateways; routing is decided by destination address **only**, unless policy routing is in effect, and in either case that happens after an application choses to bind to an interface or select a particular source addres.

Answer (score -1):

ping has defualt interface, you have to do :

```
ping -I wlan0:1 your_target
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried: `ifconfig wlan0:1 172.16.1.5
` then `ping -I wlan0:1 192.168.1.1` and I got `ping: SO_BINDTODEVICE: Invalid argument`

Comment: Oh, add your gw and routing by hand,

Comment: I R&D, It's related to shering mac, you have to define to mac address vi ifconfig or ip command.